# Why is this line of code not working? auto & whichList = theList[ myhash( kv.first) ];

Tags: c++, templates, hashtable

I have this line of in several of my member functions and they work just fine, except is this one

```
template<typename K, typename V>
    bool HashTable<K, V>::match( const std::pair<K, V> &kv ) const
    {
        auto & whichList = theLists[ myhash( kv.first ) ];
        auto itr = whichList.begin();

        for(; itr != whichList.end(); itr++)
        {
            if( (itr->first == kv.first) && (itr->second == kv.second) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the error I'm getting

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp -o main
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
HashTable.h: In instantiation of ‘bool cop4530::HashTable<K, V>::match(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) const [with K = std::basic_string<char>; V = int]’:
main.cpp:27:20:   required from here
HashTable.h:119:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘cop4530::HashTable<std::basic_string<char>, int>::myhash(const std::basic_string<char>&) const’
   auto & whichList = theLists[ myhash( kv.first ) ];
                                                 ^
HashTable.h:119:49: note: candidate is:
HashTable.h:276:9: note: size_t cop4530::HashTable<K, V>::myhash(const K&) [with K = std::basic_string<char>; V = int; size_t = long unsigned int] <near match>
  size_t HashTable<K, V>::myhash(const K & k)
         ^
HashTable.h:276:9: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const cop4530::HashTable<std::basic_string<char>, int>* const’ to ‘cop4530::HashTable<std::basic_string<char>, int>*’
makefile:2: recipe for target 'run.x' failed
make: *** [run.x] Error 1
```

Any idea why this is happening. Like I said this lines works every else I call it.

Comment: It looks like you didn't make your `myhash` function `const`.

Comment: the myhash function has a type of size_t and makes changes inside its defintion. Wouldnt const forbid that?

Comment: If `myhash` is const, it must not make changes to members of `HashTable`, unless they are declared mutable. If you can't make `myhash` const, then you can't make `match` const if it uses it.

Comment: Thank you! I just placed the implementation of hash function inside the match function and it worked

Comment: If that works, then there should be no problem in just making it const